# Numpy Matrix extension such as below:

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

My question interesed in matrix manuplations in numpy;

```
A=([[2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 3, 2 ]])
```

In this matrix the biggest value is 4 as you see. I want obtain a matrix as below, this matrix have 4 column and 10 rows (10x4) because I have 10 observation

```
B=([[0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0]])
```

first row, **second** column of  B matrix is should be 1 and others row element should be 0, because first element of A matrix is two. Similarly second row and third column shold be 1 and other row elements should be because secon element of A matrix is 3 and so on...

How  can be writen **Python**(numpy) code which give us this B matrix as output
it is very very important for me please HELP....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
A=[2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 3, 2 ]
size=[len(A),np.max(A)]
B=np.zeros(size)
for i in range(len(A)):
    idx=A[i]-1
    B[i,idx]=1
print B
```

Comment: @Kemal   You are welcome. Accept the solution though.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just want to match `A` with the list (or array) `[1,2,3,4]`, and mark the appropriate column

```
In [110]: A=np.array([2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 3, 2 ])
```

Use broadcasting to make a 2d true/false array of matches

```
In [111]: (A[:,None]==np.arange(1,5))
Out[111]: 
array([[False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False,  True],
       [ True, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

convert the T/F to 1/0 integers:

```
In [112]: (A[:,None]==np.arange(1,5)).astype(int)
Out[112]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0]])
```